# Can "it's" be used as a question?

Tags: word-usage, questions, contractions

In my experience, people say "it's" in place of "it is," but never in the form of a question. I think the question "It's?" sounds awkward, but I'd like to know if it's grammatically correct. Is it?

This question was inspired by this image on Merriam-Webster's website:
[image: It's used as a question]

Comment: "I'm?," "She's," and "He's," etc., I believe, are ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only contract auxiliary verbs, and never at the end of the sentence, where they would gain stress and therefore not be subject to reduction:

- **He’s** sleeping in today.
- **I’ve** got something to tell you.

However, these are not auxiliary verbs but principal ones falling at the end, and therefore may not be contracted:

- I  know where **he is**.
- You must be wondering what **I have**.

The contracted forms are ungrammatical there:

- I  know where ***he’s**.
- You must be wondering what **I’ve**.

Comment: Nice generalisation, but the rule against weak forms and therefore contractions is not to do with stress, just to do with stranding. For example in reply to the question "*Who's coming?*", someone is likely to answer "***I*** am!". Here the auxiliary isn't stessed but still cannot partake in a contraction. "*I'm*" is ungrammatical there.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. *It's? (ungrammatical)
> 2. It is? (grammatical)

In English every utterance must have at least one stressed syllable.

In example (1) we see a contraction of the words *it* and *is*. However we can only contract the word *is* when it isn't stressed. Because this is a one word utterance and every utterance must have a stressed syllable, this word must be stressed. And because it's stressed, this contraction is ungrammatical.

Sentence (2) is fine, because the word *is* can be stressed when it isn't contracted. We would normally pronounce this question like this :

- It ***is***?